# Automapper - ignoring mapping based on source property child item

Tags: c#, automapper

Below are my source types. In this scenario how can I ignore mapping of Pizza element when Ingredients are null or Count() == 0 ?

```
class Menu
{
    public Pizza[] Pizzas { get; set; }
}

class Pizza
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Ingredient[] Ingredients { get; set; }
}

class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


CreateMap<Menu, MenuVM>();
CreateMap<Pizza PizzaVM>();
CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientVM>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to return Ignore you can do the following (recommended):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Pizza, PizzaVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Ingredients, opt => opt.Condition(source => string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Ingredients) || src.Ingredients.Count() == 0))
```

Else you can create a ValueResolver like the following, but you would need to store the true/false result in a new field:

```
public class PizzaIngredientResolver : ValueResolver<Pizza, bool>
{
    protected override bool ResolveCore(Pizza src)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Ingredients) && src.Ingredients.Count() != 0;
    }
}
```

You will then need to call in the MappingConfiguration:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.IsIngredientVisible, opts => opts.ResolveUsing<PizzaIngredientResolver>())
```